# Static IP of Logic App Standard using Virtual Network, NAT Gateway

Tags: vnet, azure-virtual-network-gateway

I've a Logic App which needs to post a SFTP site outside of the Azure environment. The owner of the SFTP site needs the IP from which the route will come, so that they can whitelist the IP for access

I try to follow the [Logic App public IP address](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/static-ip-of-logic-app-standard-using-nat-gateway/ba-p/3721443) and this [MSFT article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway))

In the article, once author created Logic App and Virtual Network, they were able to integrate VNet in Logic App.

When I tried I got this error

[[image]]

Even though all the resources are in the same region. (How do I check to make sure all the resources used are in the same region expect manually looking at each resource?)

So, I did create Virtual Network with Address space

[image]

subnets

[image]

and NAT gateway (assigned the Virtual Network) with public IP.
[image: Public IP address]

and Virtual Network Gateway with Point-to-site configuration and assigned the Virtual Network

I then assigned the Virtual Network in the Logic Apps, Vnet Integration. I do not see the Subnets from the Virtual network

[image]

Also, I don't see the IP's of the outgoing Logic app to the one from the NAT Gateway's Public IP address.

I'm struggling with for the last three days and an wondering if someone will tell me what is the issue might be. Also, VNet Integration asks for Virtual Network Gateway (The article referenced above does not reference it and it was published on Feb 27th 2023).

I think, I'm doing something wrong or missing configuration.

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after struggling for 4 days, I was able to figure out the solution for this.

I didn't need Virtual Network Gateway. All I needed was Virtual Network and NAT gateway as mentioned in the Articles, but the VNet Integration was integrated with Azure Cli like

```
az webapp vnet-integration add --resource-group xxxx --name xxxx --vnet xxx --subnet default
```

And it worked like charm. I believe, it is better do it thru Azure Cli than Azure Portal